# Aggregation for subsets in R having same category

Tags: r

My Input is :

```
UserName    Date    Time    Module  ActiveTime
A   5/20/2015   10:00   E1  5
A   5/20/2015   10:01   E1  2
A   5/20/2015   10:02   O1  2
A   5/20/2015   10:05   Exp 4
A   5/20/2015   10:06   Exp 3
A   5/20/2015   10:06   O1  2
A   5/20/2015   10:06   Exp 5
A   5/20/2015   10:06   EXC 1
A   5/20/2015   10:06   EXC 2
A   5/20/2015   10:06   NOTE    1
B   5/20/2015   10:00   mstsc   3
B   5/20/2015   10:01   mstsc   4
B   5/20/2015   10:02   NOTE    1
B   5/20/2015   10:05   Exp 5
B   5/20/2015   10:06   Exp 1
B   5/20/2015   10:06   EXC 2
B   5/20/2015   10:06   Exp 5
B   5/20/2015   10:07   EXC 1
B   5/20/2015   10:08   EXC 2
```

Now I want to add active time for module category till the my module change not for all group.So output looklike:

```
UserName    Date    Time    Module  ActiveTime
A   5/20/2015   10:00   E1  7
A   5/20/2015   10:02   O1  2
A   5/20/2015   10:05   Exp 7
A   5/20/2015   10:06   O1  2
A   5/20/2015   10:06   Exp 5
A   5/20/2015   10:06   EXC 3
A   5/20/2015   10:06   NOTE    1
B   5/20/2015   10:00   mstsc   7
B   5/20/2015   10:02   NOTE    1
B   5/20/2015   10:05   Exp 6
B   5/20/2015   10:06   EXC 2
B   5/20/2015   10:06   Exp 5
B   5/20/2015   10:07   EXC 3
```

Any suggestion or idea.

Comment: @Akrun, i think OP just wants `sum(ActiveTime)` and `min(Time)` grouped by `UserName`, `Date` and `Module`

Comment: @dimitris_ps You could post that as an answer.  I didn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

assuming that the data frame name is `df` then

```
install.packages("dplyr") #do once if you don't have this library installed
install.packages("lubridate") #do once if you don't have this library installed

library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
newDf <- df %>% mutate(Time=hour(hm(Time))*60 + minute(hm(Time))) %>%
                group_by(UserName, Date, Module) %>% 
                summarise(Time=min(Time), ActiveTime=sum(ActiveTime)) %>% 
                mutate(Time=paste0(Time %/% 60, ":", 
                       ifelse(nchar(mod(Time, 60))==1, 
                              paste0("0", mod(Time, 60)), mod(Time, 60)))) %>% 
               select(UserName, Date, Time, Module, ActiveTime) %>% ungroup

View(newDf)
```

***Logic ***

-Convert time to minutes

-Calculate the `sum` of `ActiveTime` and the `minimum` minutes for every `UserName`, `Date`, `Module`

-Convert minutes back to `hh:mm` format.